# Orderby could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I try to use Orderby in my `Linq` query and I get the following error:

*.OrderBy(p => p.Name)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()*

Product.cs

```
public string Name =>
      NameTranslations?.FirstOrDefault( nt => nt.LanguageCode == LanguageCode.UK )?.Value;
public List<Translation> NameTranslations { get; set; }
```

so when I try to use following code I get an error:

```
var result = _db.Products.OrderBy( x => x.name);
//some logic to change resultQuery
```

I don't want to bring in-memory and use `OrderBy`, because I have some logics to change my `IQueryable`

By the way it can be solved by adding following code, but I don't want to use it like this

```
.OrderBy( x => x.NameTranslations.FirstOrDefault( nt => nt.LanguageCode == LanguageCode.UK)
                                                     .Value)
```

Comment: Looks like `Name` is an unmapped property that return this `x.NameTranslations.FirstOrDefault...`. EF can't translate that into SQL so you'll have to do it as in the last code snippert.

Answer (score 1):

As Gert said you can not use computed unmapped property in linq-to-sql.

If you just don't want to use the long expression each time you can just create a static property for it, like so:

```
public static Expression<Func<Products, string>> UkLangName =>
   Products => Products.NameTranslations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LanguageCode == LanguageCode.UK);
```

Then when you want to use it, you can do:

```
.OrderBy(UkLangName)
```